# Logreader is too slow to be functional

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am currently trying to build a script that reads all relevant lines from a ( or better, several) server logs and presents them in order. I am new to shell scripting and therefore make a lot of mistakes but now I am getting to a point where my script is so slow that it is not functional.

Here is my problem. I am first identifying a number of records by an errorcode. The line with that errorcode is a unstructured xml. In order to get the other lines associated with that error, I need to find another tag in the XML which holds an ID. That ID is matched on another line which has a timestamp and a thread or task number associated. And with those two values I could theoretically get all lines associated with my error, by looking for all lines with my thread number that are in "proximity" to my error message. In theory, as the file is 150MB large.

I have therefore build code that looks like this :

`grep -c` to get the number of errors; `grep` every line that has that error in it, write it in a file with `sed`, go over that file and find the ID, write it in an array.

Then I will do a `for` loop over the IDs and

- find the line with the ID, the task and a timestamp using `grep` over the initial file
- save task and timeline into variables
- and then loop again with read over the original file to
  find every line with my task and a timestamp that is close in seconds to my reference.

...and here it simply dies of slowness.

Doing `sed`s in a loop of `grep`s seems to not be ideal but i haven't found a tool to read a file from a specific point, say, only use lines x-y or something similar.

As the relevant lines do not start with either the line with my Errorcode or the line with my ID and Task, and several not relevant lines could be within them, I feel like I have to find them all using some form of `grep`. I know the text of the first and the last line but I have not found a way to use that to my advantage either.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edit: Yes, sorry, was a bit too vague. I have now increased the performance significantly by reducing the number of external program calls. What I did before was something like:

```
while read Buffer; do

  TimeStamp=$(echo $Buffer | sed 's/blabla(Timestamp)blabla/\1/g')
  [ TimeStamp -ge CompareStamp ] || continue
  echo $Buffer >>./mylog
done
```

So, I was looking into every line and checked the timestamp in that line whether it was close in relation to my saved timestamp. That is ridiculously slow. I substituted that code with 3 greps that only compare the timestamp part of the line and see if it fits the second of my reference or the second before or after. This works, it's just super ugly. Plus I cannot guarantee that I find just lines for my reference, as the server could process more then one case with that task in 3 seconds.

My logs look like this:

```
timestamp first entry task blabla
timestamp blabla task blabla
timestamp blabla task blabla
timestamp blabla task reference
timestamp blabla task blabla
timestamp blabla task blabla
<xml><error>error</error></error>
timestamp blabla task blabla
timestamp last entry task blabla
```

I know what last and first entry is, so I could search for it. Those blocks with identical tasks are repeated before and after this one in the logfile and lines of other tasks could be within that block as well. So my first step is to get all lines with that task into a separate file, to grep less data and to not worry about other tasks.

So in normal programming, I would now read line by line and check if it is a first entry, and always save the position of my last first entry, then upon finding my reference I would now go back to the position I saved and read every line until I would find the last entry. Is there a way to do something to that effect with shell without slowing the script down to human speed again?

Edit2: Okay, here is most of it, i have just removed the regular expressions and searchstrings:

```
grep 'Errorcode' logfile >> ./grablog
NumOfErrors=$(grep -c 'Errorcode' grablog)

AllPrimaryReferences=($(sed -r 's/^.*(<Referencetag>)([^<]*)(<\/Referencetag>).*$/\2/g' grablog))  

j=0
for ((i=0;i<NumOfErrors;i=i+2))
do

    Reference=$(grep  'blablablabla = '${AllPrimaryRefernces[i]} logfile)
    TimeStamp=$(echo "$Reference" | sed -r 's/^ganze Zeile/timestamp/g')

    AllTasks[j]=$(echo "$Reference" | sed -r 's/ganze Zeile/Reference/g')

    grep "${AllTasks[j]}" logfile >>./tempfile


    CompTimeStamp=$(date -d "$TimeStamp" +%Y-%m-%d' '%X)
    grep 'CompTimeStamp' tempfile >>./output


    rm tempfile
    let j++
done

rm grablog
´´´
```

Comment: Your question is very vague and I don't think it is answerable at all without some sample input and expected output.  Please try to update the question to address a very specific problem and include the actual code you are using.

Comment: Very wild guess would be to look into `logtail` or equivalents. As a "tool to read a file from a specific point", assuming that you want a cursor pointing to the last read offset. Or, assuming you just want to process from line N to line Q, you can probably use some combination of `tail -$Q | head -$N | <your-code>`.

Comment: Although there are quite a few options to improve shell scripting performance (like e.g. doing most things in a single (or a few) `awk` invocations which in turn do not call commands for the string processing for instance :) ), large files with XML are _really_ not a recommendable use-case for shell scripting. Consider advancing to another scripting language outside the classical "shell script" e.g. Perl. For processing large XMLs I have also made very good experiences with Java+SAX.

Comment: If there already is a program and/or library that knows how to parse that log format, I'd suggest you go with that. Otherwise, I wouldn't parse logs with shell scripting if my life depended on it. As said before, use a programming language of your choice, you will be a happier person.

Comment: I've tidied up the example code you posted (tip: scroll down and look at the Preview during future edits).  But it's still not complete enough for others to be able to investigate your problem -- you don't appear to have shown all the loops that you described earlier.  Obviously you can't include the 150MB log file, but it would help enormously if you included a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that works without us having to guess other details.

Comment: Obviously, this will not work as is. But i am grepping my errorcodes first, getting the primary references from that line. Then i am using a for loop for each primary reference, find the line with that reference and a timestamp and a task. Then i copy all lines with that task to a tempfile. Then i am looking in that file for all lines with a timestamp that matches that of my reference. But as i said, thats not exactly correct as i could get more or less entries then i should.

Comment: It's starting to make sense, but:  1) Why `i=i+2` in the main loop? Does every `ErrorCode`/`Referencetag` appear exactly twice?  2)  Your grep for each PrimaryReference (at the start of the main loop) will return *all* matching lines -- does `logfile` contain just one `blablablabla = ...` line for each PrimaryReference?  3) Do you really mean to `grep "CompTimeStamp"` from `logfile`, and not from `tempfile`?

Comment: 1) yes, they always appear twice 2) yes, this gives me one line/reference per error 3) i made a mistake here in pasting over names, this greps from tempfile

Comment: You XML segment isn't valid XML. Do the elements (and attributes) really look like your example or is it totally made up? (I don't care about the content, just the structure.)

Comment: Your example input doesn't seem to show these lines grouped by ID that you mention. We can't help if we're working from an incorrect data structure. Please provide a sample of input that matches your real world environment. Change the text of the messages by all means but please show the correct structure and layout.

Comment: Hm. This is tricky. Most of these lines look like this:
2019-11-04 23:12:18,123 INFO [description of the process] (task number) "log output".
The task number can be used to identify one group of lines and in one line there is the reference in the log output which is also in the line that contains only the xml message. in description of the process i can see the first entry and the last entryand yes, the real xml message is of course a correct one, i have oversimplified and made a mistake with the tags in doing so. I don't think i can show more, i am also not sure how it would help.

Comment: The reason you're getting all these questions and close-votes is that you keep *describing* the logfile's content, instead of simply *showing* it.  You mention that there are "groups of lines" -- please show what such a group looks like, including *every* kind of line that the script needs to use (errorcode, reference, XML, timestamps, tasks, plus whatever has to be sent to the output), so that we can run the script and see the same results as you.

Comment: I find it very encouraging how much this board tries to solve my problem, and i am thankful for it, but i don't see how providing a fully functional script would be helpful. I simply need a hint in the right direction as the script is working now. Is there a way to go through the lines of a file, looking for a substring without calling an external program for every single line and therefore slowing the script to human levels of speed? If someone knows a way to do it with the abstraction of the log i posted, i can do it with my real log. If i am wasting your time by not revealing more, sorry.

Comment: Okay, i found the right tool in grep -B/grep -A. This allows to read a bunch of lines around the one found and then i can grep them for my task and have all i need. Only problem is that i need to find the right number of trailing lines so that i don't miss any if there are a lot of loglines of other tasks in this section of the log. It's not super fast, but it will do. This can be cosidered aswered, thanks.

Comment: If you've found a solution, you can [answer your own question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), so that the work you've put in is useful to other readers.  Comments may get deleted after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few parts of your script that seem wasteful, and could be rearranged in the name of efficiency:

## Building an array

```
grep 'Errorcode' logfile >> ./grablog
NumOfErrors=$(grep -c 'Errorcode' grablog)

AllPrimaryReferences=($(sed -r 's/^.*(<Referencetag>)([^<]*)(<\/Referencetag>).*$/\2/g' grablog))
```

You've used that "NumOfErrors" later as the end-condition, with a `+=2`, while looping through the array.  You could instead access the array's length directly via `${#arrayname[@]}`.

That means you'd only have to read `grablog` once, or even better, can read from a pipeline, eliminating the temporary file:

```
AllPrimaryReferences=( $(grep 'Errorcode' logfile | sed -r '...' | uniq ) )
NumOfRefs=${#AllPrimaryReferences[@]}
```

The `uniq` should remove the duplicate entries, instead of using `+=2` to skip them. I'm assuming they're always paired up next to each other (which I can't confirm as I can't see the log file).  If not, you could add a `sort` before the `uniq`, but that's also going to be slow if there are many entries.

The part of the script inside the loop is where more attention should be focused, though.

## Extracting variables with `sed`

You're concerned that running `sed` twice every loop is slow.  Some ways you might avoid this are:

### Combining into one `sed`

Can you pipe the whole line through a single `sed` command, that extracts both variables, into an array?

```
ts_task=( $(echo "$Reference" | sed 's/\(timestamp_regex\).*\(task_regex\)/\1 \2/' ) )
timestamp="${ts_task[0]}"
task="${ts_task[1]}"
```

### Using `bash` substitutions

Perhaps you don't need `sed` at all, and can extract the substrings you need from `$References` with [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).  eg. to extract everything before the first space:

```
timestamp=${References%% *}
```

### Using a named pipe

If you're concerned that *starting* `sed` is the slow bit, you *could* start it in the background, before the loop starts, and used named pipes to communicate with the main loop.  This can get fiddly, as you need to remember which processes are hanging on read/write and background them or wait for them appropriately.

## Reading the entire input file, twice, each time round the loop

This is likely to be the slowest part, and where there is the most potential for improvement.

### Extracting the details from the Reference

You mention, in comments, that there's only one `blablabla` line per reference.  That means that the first `grep` is looking through the whole input file, and stopping at the match; then next time round, starting from the beginning again to find the next one.

If there's only one such line for each Reference, perhaps the whole "building an array" step was unnecessary, and you can feed the loop directly:

```
grep 'blablablabla = ' logfile | # match each line that defines a primary reference
  sed '...' |                    # command to extract just the timestamp and taskname
  while read ts task ; do        # assign the two required variables

    # use ts and task to extract everything as before

  done
```

This means that the first of those two `grep`s is now outside the loop, so it only runes once.

### Filtering the results

You're dumping a subset of lines to `tempfile`, then running a second `grep` over the results.  As before, you can avoid using temporary files by combining both steps into a pipeline.

```
grep "$task" logfile | grep "$timestamp" >> output
```

or if you know enough about the full line's format

```
grep "$timestamp <match other part of line> $task" logfile >> output
```

## The whole algorithm

Even with all these improvements, the bottleneck is likely to be that you're rereading the whole logfile, and examining every line in it again, for every reference/task. That's appropriate when the required lines can appear anywhere in the logfile, in any order -- it's a brute-force approach to finding every line, so it's going to take a long time.

But you've *hinted* that there are structures and context("the first and the last line", "first entry")  that would allow a smarter approach.  If you know something more about the structure/order of the input file, you can probably take further shortcuts to avoid the duplicated effort.

You asked how to "save the position" and "go back to the position I saved".  `grep -n` will report the line number of each match, and the [`tail`(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) command can skip a number of lines from the beginning of a file, though it will still need to reread the file to find the linebreaks.  Perhaps the whole file can instead be handled in a single `while read` loop?

Comment: I've used a lot of "perhaps", and some non-functional code snippets, because I still don't have much information about the input format.

Comment: Oh, that is a lot of suggestion. I will look through it all and see if i can increase performance with it. Thanks for your invested time. I am sure there is a lot of improvement in terms of performance and i will report back once i've implemented improvements. Currently my script takes around 6 seconds to get all lines for one error, it has to find a lot more though, including searching for secondary references in even more logs. Longest part by far seems to be the actual grepping of the whole files, which are even bigger than the first. So i'll start there.

Comment: Getting the length of the array with # is a great thing, this of course means that i can get rid of one grep. The file will be needed though, as i need to print the whole line anyway and won't find it with any other search. uniq works very well as well, thanks for that. Combining seds is currently not needed anymore as i am not checking for the timestamp anymore, The timestamp was only a workaround to get the lines. I am now using grep -A100 -B100 to find alle lines surrounding the reference and then i filter for the task.  not sure if it's faster, but it's correct and not too slow.

Comment: As to the rest, i will try to experiment with some of the ideas, especially the part about putting the grep outside a while loop. This could be impactful.